# Querying more than one matching array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array like this:

```
['member_1','member_2','member_15','member_1','member_1', 'member_2']
```

I noticed in the documentation that the `$in` operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array. I have 3 member_1's and 2 member_2's and 1 member_15 so my output will be only 3 when I want it to be 6.

What operator do I use so it doesn't just match one matching element in the array? I will be needing all the output of

```
 db.members.find({_id: {$in: ['member_1','member_2','member_15','member_1','member_1', 'member_2'] }})
```

gives only 3 but expected 6

Comment: Take a look at the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator.

Comment: The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array field, this is not.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you are using the `_id`  in your query criteria. Can you please elaborate? Perhaps you should add sample document with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator which will produce 5 outputs 
as in the database there are only three records consisting of id's 'member_1','member_2','member_15'.
    If still you wish to get 5 results you will have to 
fire queries multiple times using async library of mongoose
 in which you can use async series or parallel to obtain desired output.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.